# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager

Tags: jax-ws

I created a JAX WS service using annotations and used ANT to create .war and added log4j under WEB-INF/lib folder but while deploying the application in weblogic 10.3.0 I am getting the below error. I even tried by copying the log4j-1.2.8 under /lib and /lib but didnt work. But without log4j enabled I am able to successfully test the web service. Any help is appreciated.

HTTP:101216]Servlet: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:34) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:53) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:79) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:80) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.(WSEndpointImpl.java:163) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:217) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:510) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:182) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:164) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:51) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:53) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)......

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually add it to your classpath (how to do that differs from IDE but in most IDE's you can do that under the 'Libraries' project property